# MySQL inserts from Solr dataimport handler

Tags: mysql, solr, apache-tika

I am indexing pdfs and other text document with apache solr & tika from a filesystem.
I am also using `SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory` to generate unique ids for indexed files.

Since I have many files, I would like to save some information such as ids and filenames to MySQL from dataimport for later usage.

Is it possible to execute mysql insert query from solr dataimport handler with some file entity parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert into SQL from DIH itself. If you want, you can write a custom Transformer to do that and just make sure it is the last on the entity's transformer chain.

However, if you want to capture the ID you generated with UpdateProcessor, you may want to write a custom Update Processor instead, as the transformers run before the UpdateProcessors.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me with idea of custom processor, now i finally got it to work!